# $\sum_{k=1}^{+ \infty} \frac{x^{k+1}}{ k (k+1)}= x + (1-x) \ln (1-x) $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, sequence-of-function

For $x \in ]0,1[$, we want to prove, without convergence theorem, that :
$$\sum_{k=1}^{+ \infty} \dfrac{x^{k+1}}{ k (k+1)}= x  + (1-x) \ln (1-x) $$

---

My attempt :

$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^m \dfrac{x^k}{k}&= \sum_{k=1}^m \int_{0}^{x} t^{k-1} dt \\
&= \int_{0}^{x} \sum_{k=1}^m t^{k-1} dt \\
&=\int_{0}^{x} \dfrac{1- t^m}{1-t} dt \\
&= \int_{0}^{x} \dfrac{1}{1-t} dt - \int_{0}^{x} \dfrac{t^m}{1-t} dt \\
&= \ln(1-x) -  \int_{0}^{x} \dfrac{t^m}{1-t} dt \\
 \int_{0}^{x} \dfrac{t^m}{1-t} dt & \leq x^m \int_{0}^{x} \dfrac{t^m}{1-t} dt  \\
& = x^m \ln(1-x) \\
& \xrightarrow[ m \to  \infty ]{} 0 \\
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^k}{k}&= - \ln(1-x)
\end{align*}
$

I integrate term by term , and how to justify it ?

Comment: [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1457451), [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1579815), [(3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2836101), [(4)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3774182)... and a lot of posts with this as an intermediate result. (Just found [mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2265258)...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$S=\sum_{k=1}^{+ \infty} \dfrac{x^{k+1}}{ k (k+1)}$$ $$= x + (1-x) \ln (1-x) $$
Use $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k}=-\ln(1-x)$$
$$S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^{k+1}\left( \frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)=x \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k}-\sum_{j=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^j}{j}.$$
$$S=-x\ln(1-x)+\ln(1-x)+x=x+(1-x)\ln(1-x)$$

Answer (score 1):

$\int \sum_n f_n(x) dx=\sum_n \int f_n(x)$ if $f_n$ are non-negative continuous (or  measuarble ) functions. This is a special case of Tonelli's Theorem. It is also a consequence of Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Comment: Could we find a more elementary proof, and for example prove an uniform convergence ?

Answer (score 1):

If $\sum_n f_n'(x) = g'(x)$ with uniform convergence and $\sum_n f_n(x_0) =g(x_0)$ for a particular $x_0$, then $\sum_n f_n(x) = g(x)$ with uniform convergence on compact sets.

The proof is something like $$\Big\lvert\sum_{n=0}^m f_n(x) - g(x)\Big\rvert \leq\Big\lvert\sum_{n=0}^m f_n(x_0) - g(x_0)\Big\rvert+\Big\lvert\int_{x_0}^x\sum_{n=0}^mf_n'(y)-g'(y)dy\Big\lvert \leq \varepsilon(1+\lvert x-x_0\rvert)\leq\varepsilon(1+M).$$

Now, $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{k-1} = \frac1{1-x}$$ uniformly on compact subsets of $[0,1)$.
Since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{0^k}k = 0$, we obtain that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}k = -\log(1-x).$$
We can now apply it again, since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{0^{k+1}}{k(k+1)} = 0$, and deduce that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{k+1}}{k(k+1)} = x + (1-x)\log(1-x).$$